# Index doesn't increase for file renaming in multiple file upload

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have controller code for multiple upload like this:

```
$numb_receipt = count($_FILES['receipt']['name']);
$dataArray = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $numb_receipt;$i++)
{
    $today=date("dmY");
    if(!empty($_FILES['receipt']['name'][$i])){
        
        $_FILES['file']['name'] = $_FILES['receipt']['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['receipt']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['file']['type'] = $_FILES['receipt']['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['file']['error'] = $_FILES['receipt']['error'][$i];
        $_FILES['file']['size'] = $_FILES['receipt']['size'][$i];
        
        
        $config['upload_path'] = './assets/cash/receipt/'; 
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|pdf';
        $config['max_size'] = '5000';
        $config['file_name'] = 'text_'.$i.'_'.$today;
 

        $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $filename = 'assets/cash/receipt/'.$config['file_name'].'.'.$ext;
        $filename = str_replace(" ", "_", $filename);

        $this->load->library('upload',$config);
       
        
        if (!file_exists($filename)){
            echo "File not exist.";
            if($this->upload->do_upload('file')){
                $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
                $receipt['receipt'] = $uploadData['file_name'];
            }
        }
        else{
            echo "File exist.";
        }    
    }           
}
```

But when i try to print `$receipt['receipt'] = $uploadData['file_name']`
the output always shows:

```
text_0_15072020.png 
text_0_150720201.png
text_0_15072020.jpg
```

What do I need to change to get the output to look like this:

```
text_0_15072020.png
text_1_15072020.png
text_2_15072020.jpg
```

Comment: in table also inserted like this?

Comment: What have you tried to achieve this?

Comment: remove this `if(!empty($_FILES['receipt']['name'][$i])){...}else{...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to Re-initialize the Codeigniter upload library

```
$config['upload_path'] = './assets/cash/receipt/'; 
$config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|pdf';
$config['max_size'] = '5000';
$this->load->library('upload',$config);

for($i = 0; $i < $numb_receipt;$i++)
{
    $today=date("dmY");
    if(!empty($_FILES['receipt']['name'][$i])){
        
        $_FILES['file']['name'] = $_FILES['receipt']['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['receipt']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['file']['type'] = $_FILES['receipt']['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['file']['error'] = $_FILES['receipt']['error'][$i];
        $_FILES['file']['size'] = $_FILES['receipt']['size'][$i];
        
        $config['file_name'] = 'text_'.$i.'_'.$today;
        $this->upload->initialize($config); //enter new config here

        $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $filename = 'assets/cash/receipt/'.$config['file_name'].'.'.$ext;
        $filename = str_replace(" ", "_", $filename);
 
        if (!file_exists($filename)){
            echo "File not exist.";
            if($this->upload->do_upload('file')){
                $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
                $receipt['receipt'] = $uploadData['file_name'];
            }
        }
        else{
            echo "File exist.";
        }    
    }           
}
```